# unable to generate source code from avro schema files

Tags: maven, avro

I know this topic had been asked several times on this site on other places. I have performed due diligence to make sure the solutions from previous similar questions have been tried.  But still I could not make it work. The problem I have is: I could not generate source code from avro schema using maven in Eclipse(neon version with M2E installed). When I tried "mvn clean generate-sources" or "mvn clean compile", the mvn result is success, but no source codes generated in target directory.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maven-avro10 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ maven-avro10 ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\EclipseWS_forOlderProjects\maven-avro10\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.101 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-18T20:25:46-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/241M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Maven-Avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-avro10</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>maven-avro10</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     <project.basedir>C:\EclipseWS_forOlderProjects\maven-avro10</project.basedir>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>

       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-compiler</artifactId>  
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
  <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>

  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>schema</goal>
      </goals>
       <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}\src\main\avro\</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}\src\main\java\</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>

    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.7.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>

</project>
```

I tried with my own avro schema definition as well as those from Apache Avro getting started sites. For example I placed the two avsc files in ${project.basedir}\src\main\avro\
user.avsc file

```
{"namespace": "Maven_Avro.maven_avro10",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
     {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
 ]
}
```

and user1.avsc

```
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User1",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
     {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
 ]
}
```

as one of the post I read before mentioning that namespace was the problem he could not generate the source code, unfortunately that post did not explain how the namespace caused the issue and how to change the namespace in schema solves the problem.
  I have tried update Eclipse project via "maven-> update project...", I also tried to build it outside of Eclipse manually with "mvn generate-sources" or "mvn clean generate-sources", the command line build is all successful, but but just no source code is generated in target directory or any other folders.

Please let me know what I have missed or did wrong so my Eclipse (or command line) mvn build does not generate avro schema java source codes.  thanks in advance.

Comment: More information for this question/issue.  I created the maven project under Eclipse new->maven project...

Comment: Also I can use following way to generate source code in any target directory I specified.

Comment: C:\EclipseWS_forOlderProjects\maven-avro10\src\main\avro>java -jar C:\Users\hteast100\.m2\repository\org\apache\avro\avro-tools\
1.8.2\avro-tools-1.8.2.jar compile schema user.avsc  .

Comment: and I see the source code was generated in this way.  Not sure why Elcipse generate-source plugin does not work, wonder if it is related to classpath. I have checked project buildpath and see that avro-tools-1.8.2.jar is in library Maven dependencies. I even tried to re-add maven dependency via project ->Maven->add dependencies for the avro-tool dependence. But generate-source in Eclipse just does not work.

Comment: Take a look at the maven Avro plug-in. Your command line code is calling the compiler from the Avro-tools. Maven is still calling the java compiler.

Answer (score 6):

You've configured your plugins under incorrect element `<pluginManagement></pluginManagement>`, please remove this element and simply let your plugin be under `<plugins>` element.

Comment: I had a similar issue on eclipse IDE and by removing <pluginManagement></pluginManagement> solved the issue. Could you kindly explain why the pluginManagement is causing the problem here. Thanks

Comment: <pluginManagement> tag is used to manage plugin in child modules.